# Issue with XMLHttpRequest request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I have html page pulling data from another page using ajax.

The code works fine on firefox but gives an access denied on xhr.open("...")in IE and Chrome.

The sample code is as shown.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/Javascript">
        function changeContent(url)
        {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
            xhr.open("GET",url,false); //Access denied on this line
            xhr.send();
            var roster = document.getElementById("roster");
            roster.innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src=images/logo_990x80.png width=1300" height="80" />

    <div class="buttonBar">
        <input type="button" value="data" onclick="changeContent('data.html')"/>
    </div>

    <div id="roster" class="roster">
        Click on the buttons above to choose a roster
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

The data.html contains a simple table with 2 rows of data.

How can I solve this issue.

**Edit** : Code shown below works on IE and firefox but still has the same issue in Chrome.It seems ActiveX works on local files for Ajax.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/Javascript">
        function changeContent(url)
        {
        var xhr = false;
                    if(location.protocol=="file:")
        {
                if(!xhr)try{ xhr=new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP"); }catch(e){xhr=false;}
                if(!xhr)try{ xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }catch(e){xhr=false;}
            }
        else
        {
            if(!xhr)try{ xhr=new XMLHttpRequest(); }catch(e){xhr=false;}
        }   
            xhr.open("GET",url,false); //Access denied on this line only in Chrome
            xhr.send();
            var roster = document.getElementById("roster");
            roster.innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src=images/logo_990x80.png width=1300" height="80" />

    <div class="buttonBar">
        <input type="button" value="data" onclick="changeContent('data.html')"/>
    </div>

    <div id="roster" class="roster">
        Click on the buttons above to choose a roster
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Any tips for chrome.

Comment: Are you using just javascript or jQuery?

Comment: @Beneto : Just javascript

Comment: Are you able to access the url directly?

Comment: @Vinoth : Yes, If I try to access the `data.html` directly, I'm able to see the data and the code is working perfectly on Firefox but having issue in IE and Chrome as I mentioned.

Comment: for some reason `XMLHttpRequest` blocked in some browsers such as Google chrome , u need to replace ur code with jquery it better and simple did u want me to change ur code with jquery ?

Comment: @user3059001 : Sure, I can give that a try. But what is the issue with  `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: @user3059001 — Chrome does not block XHR. jQuery just wraps XHR.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by trying to use XMLHTTPRequest without using an HTTP URI.

Firefox supports XHR over `file:` scheme URIs, most browsers do not.

Run your page through a web server if you want to use Ajax.

Comment: I've updated my question and added code and it now works on IE and Firefox but still facing same issue on Chrome.

Comment: @DarkMatter — The solution is still the same: Run your page through a web server if you want to use Ajax.

Comment: Thanks, will try and get back if I face any issues.